# htaccess domain redirect strange issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all requests from domain `example.com` to `example.com.pl` which seems to be fairly easy.

What I have is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com.pl/? [R=301,NC,L]
```

But I'm getting 
`http://example.com/.pl/.pl/.pl/.pl/.pl/.pl/.pl/.pl/.pl/.pl/.pl/.pl/.pl/.pl/.pl/.pl/.pl/.pl/.pl/.pl/.pl/`
and the error is `"This web page has a redirect loop"`

Other domains caught by this rule are redirected correctly. It must have something to do with the fact that the destination domain is the original domain + '.pl'.

Comment: This seems to work ok for me. Is there anything else in your .htaccess that might be causing this?

Comment: @DerekS there is, but removing it makes no difference...

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com.pl%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Now I'm getting "page unavailable". But I've changed my redirect from example.com.pl to en.example.com.pl and it works :/ but doesn't without the "en."

Comment: You may have some DNS issues then since rule has no connection with `en` here.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the web server which is IdeaWebServer. Unfortunately I don't have access to it's config so I'd have to leave it as is.

Comment: Hmm can't help on unknown problem. But if answer helped you, you may consider accepting it.